# Migrate Horde database

Tags: mysql, postgresql, horde

I have been using Horde Webmail edition with Postgresql for the longest time. I'm in the process of migrating servers and considering dropping Postgresql in favor of MySQL. (I'm very happy with Postgresql but unfortunately there are too many applications that will only work with MySQL and I try to avoid running/maintaining both.)

What would be an elegant way to migrate the Horde database (users, calendars, etc) from Postgresql to MySQL? Is there anything better than dumping the database, fixing the syntax and importing again?

Comment: Some applications offer an export feature into a generic, application format that the app can then import into another target database. Another option for some apps is to get the app to create an empty database in the new target DB engine, clear everything out of all the tables, then migrate just the data from the old DB using an ETL tool or script then fix up any auto-generated keys. I have no direct experience with doing this for PostgreSQL=>MySQL as I only really deal with inbound PostgreSQL migrations.